# How to detect color printer with Win32?

Tags: c, winapi, printing

I have two black-and-white printers, two color printers, and some virtual printers (Fax, CutePDF Writer, etc).

According to the `DC_COLORDEVICE` query to [`DeviceCapabilities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183552(v=vs.85).aspx), only the Fax virtual printer is black-and-white.

According to `PLANES` and `BITSPIXEL` queries to [`GetDeviceCaps`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877(v=vs.85).aspx), all of the printers have one plane, and only Fax and CutePDF have 1 bit/pixel (are black-and-white).

According to the `NUMCOLORS` query to `GetDeviceCaps`, only Fax is black-and-white.

I'm not excited about [querying the driver directly](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/doc_view/printing/article.php/c6755/How-to-Determine-Whether-a-Printer-Supports-Color.htm), so I haven't tried it yet.

**How do I accurately detect a color printer with Win32?**

Comment: Chrome must do it since it provides its own print dialog which includes options for color and b&w, so you could grab the source to that and have a look.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/printing/backend/print_backend_win.cc&l=264 Looks like they use DC_COLORDEVICE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bummer that `DC_COLORDEVICE` doesn't give the right answer.  The rest of your findings don't surprise me.

You could try creating an information context for the printer with [CreateIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183505(v=vs.85).aspx), and then use [GetDeviceCaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877(v=vs.85).aspx) to check the `COLORRES` property.

(An information context is like a device context that you can query but can't actually draw to.  It's useful when you want to know what a printer driver is going to do without actually creating a real device context, which may require the printer being online.)

Checking the number of planes is useless, since everything (to a good approximation) uses a single plane.  The number of bits per pixel doesn't actually tell you if those pixels can be color or just grayscale (or just palette entries).

Another idea is to look at the `dmColor` field in the default [DEVMODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx) for the device.

I had to solve the same problem many, many years ago (before DeviceCapabilities), but I don't remember how I did it.

**UPDATE 2022-12-27:** I just came across my own answer while trying to figure out how to handle the Fax virtual printer.  When querying DeviceCapabilitiesW with `DC_COLORDEVICE`, the Fax driver returns value of -1 and GetLastError reports 122 (`ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` "The data area passed to a system call is too small.")  That's weird, since there's no requirement to pass a buffer for this query.

My current solution is to check everything.  If DeviceCapabilities with `DC_COLORDEVICE` doesn't explicitly say color OR if the DEVMODE's dmFields bitmask doesn't have the DM_COLOR bit set OR if the DEVMODE's dmColor field isn't explicitly DMCOLOR_COLOR OR if GetDeviceCaps NUMCOLORS isn't at least 8, then I assume it's a monochrome printer or that user selected monochrome for this print job.

Comment: `DEVMODE/dmColor` is probably easier, it is also accessible through `PRINTDLG` or `EnumPrinters`/`PRINTER_INFO_2` ---- `pDevMode->dmColor` is 2 for color printers.

Comment: Well, I thought I had checked `DEVMODE.dmColor`, but clearly I had not. The results are 100% accurate for all of my printers. Thanks Adrian.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't `DEVMODE.dmColor` return the default color mode? So if the printer is capable of color, but the default is B/W, then I'm left thinking it's B/W, yes?

Comment: It depends how you read `DEVMODE.dmColor` If you go through `EnumPrinters` it should always be color for color printers. However, if printer's default settings is gray-scale, and you go through `PRINTDLG` then it reads black&white. If that's the case you can override and set it back to color-mode.